# Xubuntu Wifi driver not working after update

Tags: wireless, kernel, updates, xubuntu

I'm running Xubuntu 14.04 LTS. I have a TP Link T4U USB wifi adapter, whic is based on the Realtek RTL8812AU chipset. It has been working flawlessly for a number of months, up until Linux kernel 3.13.0-77. Starting with update to kernel 3.13.0-79, and with every update since, the wifi adapter driver does not run. By all appearances, it's not even there. I can reboot and select kernel 3.13.0-77, and everything is fine again. I've modified my grub menu to offer kernel 3.13.0-77 as my first and default option, but I'd really like to fix this problem.

In kernel 3.13.0-77, here's the output of

```
    sudo lshw -C network

      *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: 82567LM-3 Gigabit Network Connection
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 19
       bus info: pci@0000:00:19.0
       logical name: eth1
       version: 02
       serial: b8:ac:6f:1d:64:14
       size: 100Mbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=e1000e driverversion=2.3.2-k duplex=full firmware=0.4-3 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=100Mbit/s
       resources: irq:48 memory:fdfe0000-fdffffff memory:fdfd9000-fdfd9fff ioport:ece0(size=32)
  *-network
       description: Wireless interface
       physical id: 1
       bus info: usb@1:2
       logical name: wlan1
       serial: c4:e9:84:09:4d:fd
       capabilities: ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=rtl8812au driverversion=3.13.0-77-generic firmware=N/A ip=192.168.0.46 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11AC
```

The wired connection is connected to an old 802.11G router I'm running in bridge mode. As you can see, the wifi router=rtl8812au is listed and working fine.

When I reboot to kernel 3.13.0-86 (current update), I get the following output of

> sudo lshw -C network

```
  *-network
   description: Ethernet interface
   product: 82567LM-3 Gigabit Network Connection
   vendor: Intel Corporation
   physical id: 19
   bus info: pci@0000:00:19.0
   logical name: eth1
   version: 02
   serial: b8:ac:6f:1d:64:14
   size: 100Mbit/s
   capacity: 1Gbit/s
   width: 32 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
   configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=e1000e driverversion=2.3.2-k duplex=full firmware=0.4-3 ip=192.168.0.40 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=100Mbit/s
   resources: irq:48 memory:fdfe0000-fdffffff memory:fdfd9000-fdfd9fff ioport:ece0(size=32)
```

As you can see, the wifi device is not even listed, as there is no operational driver. Similarly, if I run iwconfig, the wifi device is not even listed, nor is it listed in my NetworkManager. But I go back to kernel 3.13.0-77, and everything is fine again. I haven't tried reinstalling the driver, because it runs fine with the earlier kernel.

In kernel 3.13.0-86, here's the output of

> lsusb

```
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub    
Bus 008 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub    
Bus 007 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub    
Bus 006 Device 002: ID 045e:0745 Microsoft Corp. Nano Transceiver v1.0 for Bluetooth    
Bus 006 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub    
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 0781:a7c1 SanDisk Corp. Storage device (SD card reader)    
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 2357:0101    
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub    
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub    
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub    
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 051d:0002 American Power Conversion Uninterruptible Power Supply    
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
```

It looks the same in kernel 3.13.0-77. The wifi adapter is attached to bus 001 device 003 (ID 2357:0101). Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I got this solved. Chili555 was on the right track, but it did not solve the problem for me. I had modified my Grub2 so it booted into kernel 3.13.0.77 by default, but with the upgrade to LTS 16.04 (kernel 4.4.0.24), I no longer had a wifi connection even when I booted into 3.13.0.77. Looking around some more, I downloaded the package from:

https://github.com/abperiasamy/rtl8812AU_8821AU_linux

Download the zip file to your selected directory and extract it there. Navigate down one directory

```
cd rtl8812AU_8821AU_linux-master
```

dkms needs to be installed. If you don't have it, run:

```
sudo apt-get install dkms
```

The following 2 commands only need to be run once for the driver:

```
sudo cp -R . /usr/src/8812au-1.0
sudo dkms add -m 8812au -v 1.0
```

The next two commands will need to be run any time you need to rebuild and  reinstall the driver (e.g., after a kernel update that doesn't work with the previous driver):

```
sudo dkms build -m 8812au -v 1.0
sudo dkms install -m 8812au -v 1.0
```

This worked for me in both Ubuntu and Xubuntu. I'll mark this thread as SOLVED!!!

**EDIT:**

Okay, I'm editing this answer, because there was another kernel upgrade, my wifi stopped working again, I followed the procedure here, but it still didn't work. But I've become a little smarter. First of all, I learned what is called a driver in Windows is called a module in Linux, so I'll change my nomenclature. I ran the latter two commands listed above to build and install the module

```
sudo dkms build -m 8812au -v 1.0
sudo dkms install -m 8812au -v 1.0
```

but Pengy complained that it was already built and already installed. I found the actual driver file is named 8812au.ko, and is stored in the directory

```
 /lib/modules/<kernel-version>/updates/dkms
```

The current kernel version can be found from

```
 uname -r
```

Deleting that file does no good, because the module is installed inside the kernel. I could inspect boot issues with dmesg:

```
 dmesg:
 ...
 [    7.849101] 8812au: disagrees about version of symbol filp_open
 [    7.849103] 8812au: Unknown symbol filp_open (err -22)
 [    7.849165] 8812au: disagrees about version of symbol wake_up_process
 [    7.849166] 8812au: Unknown symbol wake_up_process (err -22)
 [    7.849246] 8812au: disagrees about version of symbol filp_close
 [    7.849247] 8812au: Unknown symbol filp_close (err -22)
 ...
```

That tells me that it at least tried to install the module, but failed. I could inspect the parameters of the module with modinfo:

```
 modinfo 8812au

 filename:       /lib/modules/4.4.0-36-generic/updates/dkms/8812au.ko
 version:        v4.3.8_12175.20140902
 author:         Realtek Semiconductor Corp.
 description:    Realtek Wireless Lan Driver
 license:        GPL
 ......
 vermagic:       4.4.0-34-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 686 
 ......
```

The vermagic tells me that this was compiled for kernel 4.4.0.34, whereas I am now running on kernel 4.4.0.36. Pengy took the old module and reused it. That's why it didn't work. I tried making it again, but he complained that it was already built for this kernel. I tried installing it again, and he complained that it was already installed. I tried to use the option --force, but Pengy seemed to think I was referring to what comes after --threes. I could try it multiple times changing different parameters and options, but nothing worked.

I went to my /usr/src/ directory, and saw that I had 3 different named directories of the same thing to build this module. Deleting two of them and rerunning the third didn't help. I took the 4 lines I listed above, and prepended them with two more lines to remove the module from the kernel, and delete the /usr/src/ directory tree (don't delete the directory until after the module is removed). I put these 6 lines into a script file called rebuild_t4u.sh:

```
 sudo dkms remove -m 8812au -v 1.0 -k $(uname -r);
 sudo rm -rfd /usr/src/8812au-1.0
 sudo cp -R . /usr/src/8812au-1.0
 sudo dkms add -m 8812au -v 1.0
 echo "Rebuilding 8812au -v 1.0....";
 sudo dkms build --force -m 8812au -v 1.0
 echo "Installing 8812au -v 1.0....";
 sudo dkms install --force -m 8812au -v 1.0;
```

The first line is specific to only remove the module from the current kernel, so if I need to revert to a previous kernel, it will still be there.

I had also modified the file dkms.conf to add the line

```
 MODULES_CONF_ALIAS_TYPE="wlan"
```

This will identify the module as a wlan, and will give it whatever number is next in line if there are other wlans (e.g. wlan0).

Here's the output of that run:

```
 sudo dkms build -m rtl8812au -v 1.0
 sudo dkms remove -m 8812au -v 1.0 -k 4.4.0-36-generic;
 sudo rm -rfd /usr/src/8812au-1.0
 sudo cp -R . /usr/src/8812au-1.0
 sudo dkms add -m 8812au -v 1.0

 echo "Rebuilding 8812au -v 1.0....";
 sudo dkms build --force -m 8812au -v 1.0

 echo "Installing 8812au -v 1.0....";
 sudo dkms install --force -m 8812au -v 1.0;

 ./rebuild-t4u-driver.sh

 -------- Uninstall Beginning --------
 Module:  8812au
 Version: 1.0
 Kernel:  4.4.0-36-generic (i686)
 -------------------------------------

 Status: Before uninstall, this module version was ACTIVE on this kernel.

 8812au.ko:
  - Uninstallation
    - Deleting from: /lib/modules/4.4.0-36-generic/
 rmdir: failed to remove '': No such file or directory
  - Original module
    - No original module was found for this module on this kernel.
    - Use the dkms install command to reinstall any previous module      version.

 depmod....

 DKMS: uninstall completed.
 Error! DKMS tree already contains: 8812au-1.0
 You cannot add the same module/version combo more than once.
 Rebuilding 8812au -v 1.0....

 Kernel preparation unnecessary for this kernel.  Skipping...

 Building module:
 cleaning build area....
 'make' KVER=4.4.0-36-generic..................
 cleaning build area....

 DKMS: build completed.
 Installing 8812au -v 1.0....

 8812au:
 Running module version sanity check.
  - Original module
    - No original module exists within this kernel
  - Installation
    - Installing to /lib/modules/4.4.0-36-generic/updates/dkms/

 /etc/modprobe.d/dkms.conf: added alias reference for '8812au'
 depmod....

 DKMS: install completed.
```

Well, that looked promising, but it still wasn't running. Trying different things, I entered the tried and true command:

```
 ifconfig wlan0 up
```

Bing. The light immediately started flashing on the USB adapter. So now it was turned on. But I still had no WIFI access. I went into Network Manager GUI, and it still didn't show any WIFI connections. I tried several more things, none of which worked, but then came across the suggestion to:

```
 With the computer running, unplug the adapter and plug it in again.
```

Bing! Bing! Bing! That's what finally did it. I'm up on wifi again! It might have come up if I had rebooted, but this saved me from having to do that (but probably took longer trying to figure that out).

So, to summarize, download the module package, install dkms modify the dkms.conf file in the package to create the alias, take the 6 commands above and put them in a script file in the package root directory, run it, run the command "ifconfig wlan? up", and unplug and replug the adapter or reboot your computer. This procedure should work for other wifi adapters besides the Realtek that have a similar problem.

**EDIT 2:**

I've rebooted several times and this is still working. The only thing is than the normal device names had changed when I issue the commands ifconfig or iwconfig. You need to create a file

```
/etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules.
```

In it, add the line

```
SUBSYSTEM=="net",  ACTION=="add",  DRIVERS=="?*",  ATTR{address}=="<MAC-ID>", ATTR{dev_id}=="0x0", ATTR{type}=="1", NAME="<dev-name>"
```

Where MAC-ID is the name of the device, and dev-name is what you want to call it. Be aware that older versions of this file also had a field

```
KERNEL=="wlan*"
```

The new kernel doesn't like this, and will ignore the entire line if this field is included, so if you're making use of an older version of this file, delete this field.

Answer (score 0):

The driver *rtl8812au* doesn't exist natively in kernel version 3.13.0-xx. I am certain that, in order to get it working in -77, you downloaded it and compiled it from source code. However, when a later kernel version is installed by Update Manager, in your case, -79, it is necessary to re-compile.

You can utilize the DKMS procedure to have this done automatically. With a working internet connection and booted into -86, please do:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install git dkms
git clone https://github.com/abperiasamy/rtl8812AU_8821AU_linux.git
sudo dkms add ./rtl8812AU_8821AU_linux
sudo dkms install -m 8812au -v 1.0
```

Your wireless should then be working.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your help, Chili555, but this didn't fix it. While running in the -86 kernel, I ran the commands you listed one at time, which all worked fine, until the last one. The output to the command

`sudo dkms install -m 8812au -v 1.0`

is:

```
Kernel preparation unnecessary for this kernel.  Skipping...

Building module:
cleaning build area....
'make'...................
cleaning build area....

DKMS: build completed.

8812au.ko:
Running module version sanity check.
Error! Module version v4.2.2_7502.20130517 for 8812au.ko
is not newer than what is already found in kernel 3.13.0-86-generic (v4.2.2_7502.20130517).
You may override by specifying --force.

depmod....

DKMS: install completed.
```

So I reran the command with --force added"

`sudo dkms install --force -m 8812au -v 1.0`

The output is:

`Module 8812au/1.0 already installed on kernel 3.13.0-86-generic/i686`

So still no diff on having a functioning driver.

I looked at the second to last command you gave me. Here's the output:

```
sudo dkms add ./rtl8812AU_8821AU_linux

Creating symlink /var/lib/dkms/8812au/1.0/source ->
                 /usr/src/8812au-1.0

DKMS: add completed.
```

I next wanted to see what was in /var/lib/dkms

```
cd /var/lib/dkms

[/var/lib/dkms]
[home4-randy]:ll
total 16
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4096 26.05.2016 23:57 8812au
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4096 10.05.2016 10:15 nvidia-304
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4096 10.05.2016 10:15 rtl8812AU_8821AU_linux
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    6 08.07.2008 08:19 dkms_dbversion

[/var/lib/dkms]
[home4-randy]:ll 8812au
total 4
drwxr-xr-x 4 root root 4096 26.05.2016 23:57 1.0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   26 26.05.2016 23:57 kernel-3.13.0-86-generic-i686 -> 1.0/3.13.0-86-generic/i686

[/var/lib/dkms]
[home4-randy]:ll rtl*
total 4
drwxr-xr-x 17 root root 4096 10.05.2016 10:15 1.0
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root   26 20.09.2015 11:49 kernel-3.13.0-46-generic-i686 -> 1.0/3.13.0-46-generic/i686
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root   26 10.09.2015 10:23 kernel-3.13.0-63-generic-i686 -> 1.0/3.13.0-63-generic/i686
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root   26 28.09.2015 23:30 kernel-3.13.0-65-generic-i686 -> 1.0/3.13.0-65-generic/i686
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root   26 21.10.2015 13:09 kernel-3.13.0-66-generic-i686 -> 1.0/3.13.0-66-generic/i686
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root   26 05.11.2015 09:12 kernel-3.13.0-67-generic-i686 -> 1.0/3.13.0-67-generic/i686
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root   26 18.11.2015 14:23 kernel-3.13.0-68-generic-i686 -> 1.0/3.13.0-68-generic/i686
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root   26 02.12.2015 14:11 kernel-3.13.0-71-generic-i686 -> 1.0/3.13.0-71-generic/i686
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root   26 31.12.2015 10:33 kernel-3.13.0-74-generic-i686 -> 1.0/3.13.0-74-generic/i686
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root   26 21.01.2016 18:37 kernel-3.13.0-76-generic-i686 -> 1.0/3.13.0-76-generic/i686
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root   26 03.02.2016 23:43 kernel-3.13.0-77-generic-i686 -> 1.0/3.13.0-77-generic/i686
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root   26 04.03.2016 10:49 kernel-3.13.0-79-generic-i686 -> 1.0/3.13.0-79-generic/i686
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root   26 15.03.2016 23:38 kernel-3.13.0-83-generic-i686 -> 1.0/3.13.0-83-generic/i686
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root   26 06.04.2016 12:54 kernel-3.13.0-85-generic-i686 -> 1.0/3.13.0-85-generic/i686
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root   26 10.05.2016 10:15 kernel-3.13.0-86-generic-i686 -> 1.0/3.13.0-86-generic/i686
```

So it looks as if the driver you had me rebuild is in directory /var/lib/dkms/8812au. Also,  in directory /var/lib/dkms/rtl8812AU_8821AU_linux, there is a wifi driver already built for each kernel upgrade I had installed. So if the wifi driver is already built specific for the kernel, why does it not work for the more recent versions? I'm wondering if there is a change in these newer kernels which is not reflected in the driver, rendering the driver software obsolete?

As these are only the symbolic links, I followed them down...
For the build you had me compile, here's the make.log file:

```
DKMS make.log for 8812au-1.0 for kernel 3.13.0-86-generic (i686)
Thu May 26 23:57:04 MST 2016
make ARCH=i386 CROSS_COMPILE= -C /lib/modules/3.13.0-86-generic/build M=/var/lib/dkms/8812au/1.0/build  modules
make[1]: Entering directory `/usr/src/linux-headers-3.13.0-86-generic'
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/8812au/1.0/build/core/rtw_cmd.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/8812au/1.0/build/core/rtw_security.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/8812au/1.0/build/core/rtw_debug.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/8812au/1.0/build/core/rtw_io.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/8812au/1.0/build/core/rtw_ioctl_query.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/8812au/1.0/build/core/rtw_ioctl_set.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/8812au/1.0/build/core/rtw_ieee80211.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/8812au/1.0/build/core/rtw_mlme.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/8812au/1.0/build/core/rtw_mlme_ext.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/8812au/1.0/build/core/rtw_wlan_util.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/8812au/1.0/build/core/rtw_vht.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/8812au/1.0/build/core/rtw_pwrctrl.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/8812au/1.0/build/core/rtw_rf.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/8812au/1.0/build/core/rtw_recv.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/8812au/1.0/build/core/rtw_sta_mgt.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/8812au/1.0/build/core/rtw_ap.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/8812au/1.0/build/core/rtw_xmit.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/8812au/1.0/build/core/rtw_p2p.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/8812au/1.0/build/core/rtw_tdls.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/8812au/1.0/build/core/rtw_br_ext.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/8812au/1.0/build/core/rtw_iol.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/8812au/1.0/build/core/rtw_sreset.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/8812au/1.0/build/core/efuse/rtw_efuse.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/8812au/1.0/build/os_dep/osdep_service.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/8812au/1.0/build/os_dep/linux/os_intfs.o
/var/lib/dkms/8812au/1.0/build/os_dep/linux/os_intfs.c:1702:2: warning: initialization from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]
  .ndo_select_queue = rtw_select_queue,
  ^
/var/lib/dkms/8812au/1.0/build/os_dep/linux/os_intfs.c:1702:2: warning: (near initialization for ‘rtw_netdev_ops.ndo_select_queue’) [enabled by default]
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/8812au/1.0/build/os_dep/linux/usb_intf.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/8812au/1.0/build/os_dep/linux/usb_ops_linux.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/8812au/1.0/build/os_dep/linux/ioctl_linux.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/8812au/1.0/build/os_dep/linux/xmit_linux.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/8812au/1.0/build/os_dep/linux/mlme_linux.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/8812au/1.0/build/os_dep/linux/recv_linux.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/8812au/1.0/build/os_dep/linux/ioctl_cfg80211.o
/var/lib/dkms/8812au/1.0/build/os_dep/linux/ioctl_cfg80211.c:5109:2: warning: initialization from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]
  .get_station = cfg80211_rtw_get_station,
  ^
/var/lib/dkms/8812au/1.0/build/os_dep/linux/ioctl_cfg80211.c:5109:2: warning: (near initialization for ‘rtw_cfg80211_ops.get_station’) [enabled by default]
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/8812au/1.0/build/os_dep/linux/rtw_android.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/8812au/1.0/build/hal/hal_intf.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/8812au/1.0/build/hal/hal_com.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/8812au/1.0/build/hal/hal_com_phycfg.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/8812au/1.0/build/hal/hal_phy.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/8812au/1.0/build/hal/led/hal_usb_led.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/8812au/1.0/build/hal/HalPwrSeqCmd.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/8812au/1.0/build/hal/rtl8812a/Hal8812PwrSeq.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/8812au/1.0/build/hal/rtl8812a/Hal8821APwrSeq.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/8812au/1.0/build/hal/rtl8812a/rtl8812a_xmit.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/8812au/1.0/build/hal/rtl8812a/rtl8812a_sreset.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/8812au/1.0/build/hal/rtl8812a/rtl8812a_hal_init.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/8812au/1.0/build/hal/rtl8812a/rtl8812a_phycfg.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/8812au/1.0/build/hal/rtl8812a/rtl8812a_rf6052.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/8812au/1.0/build/hal/rtl8812a/rtl8812a_dm.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/8812au/1.0/build/hal/rtl8812a/rtl8812a_rxdesc.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/8812au/1.0/build/hal/rtl8812a/rtl8812a_cmd.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/8812au/1.0/build/hal/rtl8812a/usb/usb_halinit.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/8812au/1.0/build/hal/rtl8812a/usb/rtl8812au_led.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/8812au/1.0/build/hal/rtl8812a/usb/rtl8812au_xmit.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/8812au/1.0/build/hal/rtl8812a/usb/rtl8812au_recv.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/8812au/1.0/build/hal/rtl8812a/usb/usb_ops_linux.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/8812au/1.0/build/hal/rtl8812a/rtl8812a_mp.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/8812au/1.0/build/hal/OUTSRC/odm_debug.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/8812au/1.0/build/hal/OUTSRC/odm_interface.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/8812au/1.0/build/hal/OUTSRC/odm_HWConfig.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/8812au/1.0/build/hal/OUTSRC/odm.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/8812au/1.0/build/hal/OUTSRC/HalPhyRf.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/8812au/1.0/build/hal/OUTSRC/rtl8812a/HalHWImg8812A_FW.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/8812au/1.0/build/hal/OUTSRC/rtl8812a/HalHWImg8812A_MAC.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/8812au/1.0/build/hal/OUTSRC/rtl8812a/HalHWImg8812A_BB.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/8812au/1.0/build/hal/OUTSRC/rtl8812a/HalHWImg8812A_RF.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/8812au/1.0/build/hal/OUTSRC/rtl8812a/HalHWImg8812A_TestChip_FW.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/8812au/1.0/build/hal/OUTSRC/rtl8812a/HalHWImg8812A_TestChip_MAC.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/8812au/1.0/build/hal/OUTSRC/rtl8812a/HalHWImg8812A_TestChip_BB.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/8812au/1.0/build/hal/OUTSRC/rtl8812a/HalHWImg8812A_TestChip_RF.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/8812au/1.0/build/hal/OUTSRC/rtl8812a/HalPhyRf_8812A.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/8812au/1.0/build/hal/OUTSRC/rtl8812a/odm_RegConfig8812A.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/8812au/1.0/build/hal/OUTSRC/rtl8821a/HalHWImg8821A_FW.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/8812au/1.0/build/hal/OUTSRC/rtl8821a/HalHWImg8821A_MAC.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/8812au/1.0/build/hal/OUTSRC/rtl8821a/HalHWImg8821A_BB.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/8812au/1.0/build/hal/OUTSRC/rtl8821a/HalHWImg8821A_RF.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/8812au/1.0/build/hal/OUTSRC/rtl8821a/HalHWImg8821A_TestChip_MAC.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/8812au/1.0/build/hal/OUTSRC/rtl8821a/HalHWImg8821A_TestChip_BB.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/8812au/1.0/build/hal/OUTSRC/rtl8821a/HalHWImg8821A_TestChip_RF.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/8812au/1.0/build/hal/OUTSRC/rtl8821a/HalPhyRf_8821A.o
  CC [M] /var/lib/dkms/8812au/1.0/build/hal/OUTSRC/rtl8821a/odm_RegConfig8821A.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/8812au/1.0/build/core/rtw_mp.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/8812au/1.0/build/core/rtw_mp_ioctl.o
  LD [M]  /var/lib/dkms/8812au/1.0/build/8812au.o
  Building modules, stage 2.
  MODPOST 1 modules
  CC      /var/lib/dkms/8812au/1.0/build/8812au.mod.o
  LD [M]  /var/lib/dkms/8812au/1.0/build/8812au.ko
make[1]: Leaving directory `/usr/src/linux-headers-3.13.0-86-generic'
```

I then looked at the make.log file for the one previously build automatically with the update:

```
DKMS make.log for rtl8812AU_8821AU_linux-1.0 for kernel 3.13.0-86-generic (i686)
Tue May 10 10:15:03 MST 2016
make ARCH=i386 CROSS_COMPILE= -C /lib/modules/3.13.0-77-generic/build M=/var/lib/dkms/rtl8812AU_8821AU_linux/1.0/build  modules
make[1]: Entering directory `/usr/src/linux-headers-3.13.0-77-generic'
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtl8812AU_8821AU_linux/1.0/build/core/rtw_cmd.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtl8812AU_8821AU_linux/1.0/build/core/rtw_security.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtl8812AU_8821AU_linux/1.0/build/core/rtw_debug.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtl8812AU_8821AU_linux/1.0/build/core/rtw_io.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtl8812AU_8821AU_linux/1.0/build/core/rtw_ioctl_query.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtl8812AU_8821AU_linux/1.0/build/core/rtw_ioctl_set.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtl8812AU_8821AU_linux/1.0/build/core/rtw_ieee80211.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtl8812AU_8821AU_linux/1.0/build/core/rtw_mlme.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtl8812AU_8821AU_linux/1.0/build/core/rtw_mlme_ext.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtl8812AU_8821AU_linux/1.0/build/core/rtw_wlan_util.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtl8812AU_8821AU_linux/1.0/build/core/rtw_vht.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtl8812AU_8821AU_linux/1.0/build/core/rtw_pwrctrl.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtl8812AU_8821AU_linux/1.0/build/core/rtw_rf.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtl8812AU_8821AU_linux/1.0/build/core/rtw_recv.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtl8812AU_8821AU_linux/1.0/build/core/rtw_sta_mgt.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtl8812AU_8821AU_linux/1.0/build/core/rtw_ap.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtl8812AU_8821AU_linux/1.0/build/core/rtw_xmit.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtl8812AU_8821AU_linux/1.0/build/core/rtw_p2p.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtl8812AU_8821AU_linux/1.0/build/core/rtw_tdls.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtl8812AU_8821AU_linux/1.0/build/core/rtw_br_ext.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtl8812AU_8821AU_linux/1.0/build/core/rtw_iol.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtl8812AU_8821AU_linux/1.0/build/core/rtw_sreset.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtl8812AU_8821AU_linux/1.0/build/core/efuse/rtw_efuse.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtl8812AU_8821AU_linux/1.0/build/os_dep/osdep_service.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtl8812AU_8821AU_linux/1.0/build/os_dep/linux/os_intfs.o
/var/lib/dkms/rtl8812AU_8821AU_linux/1.0/build/os_dep/linux/os_intfs.c:1702:2: warning: initialization from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]
  .ndo_select_queue = rtw_select_queue,
  ^
/var/lib/dkms/rtl8812AU_8821AU_linux/1.0/build/os_dep/linux/os_intfs.c:1702:2: warning: (near initialization for ‘rtw_netdev_ops.ndo_select_queue’) [enabled by default]
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtl8812AU_8821AU_linux/1.0/build/os_dep/linux/usb_intf.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtl8812AU_8821AU_linux/1.0/build/os_dep/linux/usb_ops_linux.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtl8812AU_8821AU_linux/1.0/build/os_dep/linux/ioctl_linux.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtl8812AU_8821AU_linux/1.0/build/os_dep/linux/xmit_linux.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtl8812AU_8821AU_linux/1.0/build/os_dep/linux/mlme_linux.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtl8812AU_8821AU_linux/1.0/build/os_dep/linux/recv_linux.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtl8812AU_8821AU_linux/1.0/build/os_dep/linux/ioctl_cfg80211.o
/var/lib/dkms/rtl8812AU_8821AU_linux/1.0/build/os_dep/linux/ioctl_cfg80211.c:5099:2: warning: initialization from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]
  .add_station = cfg80211_rtw_add_station,
  ^
/var/lib/dkms/rtl8812AU_8821AU_linux/1.0/build/os_dep/linux/ioctl_cfg80211.c:5099:2: warning: (near initialization for ‘rtw_cfg80211_ops.add_station’) [enabled by default]
/var/lib/dkms/rtl8812AU_8821AU_linux/1.0/build/os_dep/linux/ioctl_cfg80211.c:5100:2: warning: initialization from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]
  .del_station = cfg80211_rtw_del_station,
  ^
/var/lib/dkms/rtl8812AU_8821AU_linux/1.0/build/os_dep/linux/ioctl_cfg80211.c:5100:2: warning: (near initialization for ‘rtw_cfg80211_ops.del_station’) [enabled by default]
/var/lib/dkms/rtl8812AU_8821AU_linux/1.0/build/os_dep/linux/ioctl_cfg80211.c:5101:2: warning: initialization from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]
  .change_station = cfg80211_rtw_change_station,
  ^
/var/lib/dkms/rtl8812AU_8821AU_linux/1.0/build/os_dep/linux/ioctl_cfg80211.c:5101:2: warning: (near initialization for ‘rtw_cfg80211_ops.change_station’) [enabled by default]
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtl8812AU_8821AU_linux/1.0/build/os_dep/linux/rtw_android.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtl8812AU_8821AU_linux/1.0/build/hal/hal_intf.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtl8812AU_8821AU_linux/1.0/build/hal/hal_com.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtl8812AU_8821AU_linux/1.0/build/hal/hal_com_phycfg.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtl8812AU_8821AU_linux/1.0/build/hal/hal_phy.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtl8812AU_8821AU_linux/1.0/build/hal/led/hal_usb_led.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtl8812AU_8821AU_linux/1.0/build/hal/HalPwrSeqCmd.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtl8812AU_8821AU_linux/1.0/build/hal/rtl8812a/Hal8812PwrSeq.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtl8812AU_8821AU_linux/1.0/build/hal/rtl8812a/Hal8821APwrSeq.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtl8812AU_8821AU_linux/1.0/build/hal/rtl8812a/rtl8812a_xmit.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtl8812AU_8821AU_linux/1.0/build/hal/rtl8812a/rtl8812a_sreset.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtl8812AU_8821AU_linux/1.0/build/hal/rtl8812a/rtl8812a_hal_init.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtl8812AU_8821AU_linux/1.0/build/hal/rtl8812a/rtl8812a_phycfg.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtl8812AU_8821AU_linux/1.0/build/hal/rtl8812a/rtl8812a_rf6052.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtl8812AU_8821AU_linux/1.0/build/hal/rtl8812a/rtl8812a_dm.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtl8812AU_8821AU_linux/1.0/build/hal/rtl8812a/rtl8812a_rxdesc.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtl8812AU_8821AU_linux/1.0/build/hal/rtl8812a/rtl8812a_cmd.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtl8812AU_8821AU_linux/1.0/build/hal/rtl8812a/usb/usb_halinit.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtl8812AU_8821AU_linux/1.0/build/hal/rtl8812a/usb/rtl8812au_led.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtl8812AU_8821AU_linux/1.0/build/hal/rtl8812a/usb/rtl8812au_xmit.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtl8812AU_8821AU_linux/1.0/build/hal/rtl8812a/usb/rtl8812au_recv.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtl8812AU_8821AU_linux/1.0/build/hal/rtl8812a/usb/usb_ops_linux.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtl8812AU_8821AU_linux/1.0/build/hal/rtl8812a/rtl8812a_mp.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtl8812AU_8821AU_linux/1.0/build/hal/OUTSRC/odm_debug.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtl8812AU_8821AU_linux/1.0/build/hal/OUTSRC/odm_interface.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtl8812AU_8821AU_linux/1.0/build/hal/OUTSRC/odm_HWConfig.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtl8812AU_8821AU_linux/1.0/build/hal/OUTSRC/odm.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtl8812AU_8821AU_linux/1.0/build/hal/OUTSRC/HalPhyRf.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtl8812AU_8821AU_linux/1.0/build/hal/OUTSRC/rtl8812a/HalHWImg8812A_FW.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtl8812AU_8821AU_linux/1.0/build/hal/OUTSRC/rtl8812a/HalHWImg8812A_MAC.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtl8812AU_8821AU_linux/1.0/build/hal/OUTSRC/rtl8812a/HalHWImg8812A_BB.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtl8812AU_8821AU_linux/1.0/build/hal/OUTSRC/rtl8812a/HalHWImg8812A_RF.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtl8812AU_8821AU_linux/1.0/build/hal/OUTSRC/rtl8812a/HalHWImg8812A_TestChip_FW.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtl8812AU_8821AU_linux/1.0/build/hal/OUTSRC/rtl8812a/HalHWImg8812A_TestChip_MAC.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtl8812AU_8821AU_linux/1.0/build/hal/OUTSRC/rtl8812a/HalHWImg8812A_TestChip_BB.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtl8812AU_8821AU_linux/1.0/build/hal/OUTSRC/rtl8812a/HalHWImg8812A_TestChip_RF.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtl8812AU_8821AU_linux/1.0/build/hal/OUTSRC/rtl8812a/HalPhyRf_8812A.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtl8812AU_8821AU_linux/1.0/build/hal/OUTSRC/rtl8812a/odm_RegConfig8812A.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtl8812AU_8821AU_linux/1.0/build/hal/OUTSRC/rtl8821a/HalHWImg8821A_FW.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtl8812AU_8821AU_linux/1.0/build/hal/OUTSRC/rtl8821a/HalHWImg8821A_MAC.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtl8812AU_8821AU_linux/1.0/build/hal/OUTSRC/rtl8821a/HalHWImg8821A_BB.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtl8812AU_8821AU_linux/1.0/build/hal/OUTSRC/rtl8821a/HalHWImg8821A_RF.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtl8812AU_8821AU_linux/1.0/build/hal/OUTSRC/rtl8821a/HalHWImg8821A_TestChip_MAC.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtl8812AU_8821AU_linux/1.0/build/hal/OUTSRC/rtl8821a/HalHWImg8821A_TestChip_BB.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtl8812AU_8821AU_linux/1.0/build/hal/OUTSRC/rtl8821a/HalHWImg8821A_TestChip_RF.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtl8812AU_8821AU_linux/1.0/build/hal/OUTSRC/rtl8821a/HalPhyRf_8821A.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtl8812AU_8821AU_linux/1.0/build/hal/OUTSRC/rtl8821a/odm_RegConfig8821A.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtl8812AU_8821AU_linux/1.0/build/core/rtw_mp.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtl8812AU_8821AU_linux/1.0/build/core/rtw_mp_ioctl.o
  LD [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtl8812AU_8821AU_linux/1.0/build/8812au.o
  Building modules, stage 2.
  MODPOST 1 modules
  CC      /var/lib/dkms/rtl8812AU_8821AU_linux/1.0/build/8812au.mod.o
  LD [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtl8812AU_8821AU_linux/1.0/build/8812au.ko
make[1]: Leaving directory `/usr/src/linux-headers-3.13.0-77-generic'
```

I see warnings in both compiles, but don't know how significant they are. If you have any further ideas on this, I'd be happy to hear them. Thanks.